# Chamada duplicada do evento onclick no Delphi

Tags: delphi, eventos, onclick

Ao executar o evento onclick (do botao btn_ImportarNFe) o programa chama o mesmo evento onclick novamente a partir da chamada do método `Nfe.EnviarEvento(StrToInt(IDLote));` do segundo trecho de código (ver listagem completa abaixo). Ao executar o mesmo evento onclick em modo debug essa segunda chamada não acontece.

Trecho de código da Procedure ImportarNFe:

```
    procedure Tfrm_LancamentosDespesas.btn_ImportarNFeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dlgImportarNFe       : TFrm_BuscarChave;
  Chave, CNPJ, idLote  : string;
  i                    : Integer;
  XMLtsl               : TStringList;
  XMLStream            : TStringStream;
begin
  dlgImportarNFe :=  TFrm_BuscarChave.Create(nil);
  XMLtsl    := TStringList.Create;
  XMLStream := TStringStream.Create;

  dlgImportarNFe.ShowModal;

  if dlgImportarNFe.ModalResult = mrCancel then
  begin
    Exit
  end
  else
  begin
    if dlgImportarNFe.chk_BuscarXML.Checked = False then
    begin
      Chave          := dlgImportarNFe.edt_Chave.Text;
      CNPJ           := dm.EmpresaControlada.CGC;
      idLote         := '1';

      dlgImportarNFe.free;

      dm_NFe.EventoConfirmacao(Chave, idLote, CNPJ);
      dm_NFe.DistribuicaoDFePorChaveNFe(31, CNPJ, Chave);
      op.FileName    := dm_NFe.nfe.Configuracoes.Arquivos.DownloadNFe.PathDownload + dm_NFe.nfe.WebServices.DistribuicaoDFe.ListaArqs[0];
    end;
...
```

Trecho de código com método EnviarEvento :

```
procedure Tdm_NFe.EventoConfirmacao(Chave, idLote, CNPJ: string);
var
  lMsg      : string;
  RetornoWS : string;
begin
  Chave  := Trim(OnlyNumber(Chave));
  idLote := Trim(OnlyNumber(idLote));
  CNPJ   := Trim(OnlyNumber(CNPJ));

  nfe.Configuracoes.WebServices.Ambiente      := dm_NFe.tipoAmbiente;
  nfe.Configuracoes.Certificados.NumeroSerie  := dm_logon.dat_EmpresaCTRLNUMSERIE_NFE.AsString;
  nfe.Configuracoes.WebServices.UF            := 'MG';
  DataModuleCreate(nil);

  Nfe.EventoNFe.Evento.Clear;
  with Nfe.EventoNFe.Evento.Add do
  begin
    InfEvento.cOrgao   := 91;
    infEvento.chNFe    := Chave;
    infEvento.CNPJ     := CNPJ;
    infEvento.dhEvento := now;
    infEvento.tpEvento := teManifDestConfirmacao;
  end;

  Nfe.EnviarEvento(StrToInt(IDLote));
...
```

Alguem sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Matheus, você consegue colocar alguma coisa para "rastrear" onde exatamente está acontecendo isso? Coloque algumas partes do código com "try...catch" para ver se está captando alguma excessão. Algumas mensagens exibindo valores de variáveis com ShowMessage também pode ajudar.

Comment: Já foi colocado e como não retornou nada foi retirado.

Comment: De acordo com você _programa chama o mesmo evento onclick novamente a partir da chamada do método Nfe.EnviarEvento(StrToInt(IDLote));_... O que tem dentro do método Nfe.EnviarEvento?

Comment: Nfe.EnviarEvento(StrToInt(IDLote)); e onde são feitas as devidas verificações para envio do evento para o governo, especificamente neste trecho  Result := WebServices.EnvEvento.Executar; acontece a duplicidade.

Comment: Consegui solucionar o problema, o que estava acontecendo e que eu não estava limpando objeto antes de usa-lo. logo  depois de abrir  dlgImportarNFe.ShowModal;, foi inserido dm_NFe.nfe.NotasFiscais.Clear; para limpar o objeto.